# How to send a lot of files from server to client using express (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to send files from NodeJS server to clients. Many images, css files, js files. For a few files I use

```
app.get('/js/client.js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'client.js'));
});
```

The path is `var path = require('path');`

So, if I use this construction for every file I want to send, this part of the code will be huge. How can I simplify it?

Comment: Why don't you use `static` middleware for that?

Comment: What is that and how to use it?

Comment: You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting posts on the site.

Comment: @levshkatov may be you will try to google that?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yeah, you're right. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve static content, put all content in public folder in will be automatically served using express.

```
    app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));
```

Comment: Everything is ok if public folder is in folder with server.js script. But if it is in root directory `../public` doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I should use `/../public`. Sorry.